# Выделение атрибута в XML

Tags: c#, xml, url

Есть XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Properties>
  <browser name = "Chrome"/>
  <url name = "https://www.onliner.by/"/>
  <waitTime name = "60"/>
</Properties>
```

Нужно атрибут `name` элемента `url` засунуть в переменную.
Я это делаю так

```
static XmlTextReader readerBrowser = new XmlTextReader("..\\..\\Properties Of Framework.xml"); 
readerBrowser.ReadToFollowing("url"); 
string MyString = readerBrowser.GetAttribute(Attribute);
```

но при повторном вызове данный метод не работает. Как я понял из за `ReadToFollowing`. Подскажите другой метод обращения чтобы я мог многократно использовать.

Comment: А зачем вам повторное чтение одного и того же значения? Прочитайте один раз, запомните в переменной.

Comment: @VladD исходя из реализации моего фреймворка, так, к сожалению , не получится.

Comment: Ну тогда создавайте каждый раз новый `XmlTextReader` в вашем методе, например. Не вполне понятно, откуда такое ограничение, если честно.

Comment: @VlaD нужно именно многократное обращение, а лишние переменные это не очень хорошо во фреймворке + я многократно вызываю этот метод с разными параметрами и все их записывать в переменные не очень удобно

Comment: Тогда если можно, покажите то, с какими переменными будет вызываться метод. Покамест мне кажется, что вы слишком упростили условие, в результате чего у вашей задачи появилось тривиальное решение.

Comment: Нужно именно `XmlTextReader` использовать? может `XDocument` лучше?

Comment: @Sv_t а как там переход к элементу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде уже отвечал Вам. В этом случае так:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("..\\..\\PropertiesOfFramework.xml");
string MyString = (string)xdoc.Root.Element("url").Attribute("name");
```

Comment: @PavelMayorov, почему свойство `XAttribute.Value` здесь не подходит?

Comment: Просто не мешает лишний раз напомнить о том, что XAttribute можно кастовать к примитивным типам. Для того же waitTime это уже упростит код автора вопроса.